# Can you get the 'x' (close) button on a bootstrap modal to call a javascript function instead of closing the modal?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm implementing a bootstrap modal and need to change the functionality of the 'close' button (the small x in the upper right corner). I want that to call a javascript function *instead of closing the modal*. This is for a research project and not a production web site (I realize this would likely always be a bad idea on a live site).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you just have to use the modal's 'hide' event. [See the docs.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events)

```
$("#exampleModal").on("hide.bs.modal", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
          //do whatever here
 });
```